# Check if a data frame is itself NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

How can I check if an R data frame is empty? Check out this code. I want to modify it so it never produces an error or warning.

```
x = sample(1:2,1)
d = NA
if(x == 1) {
    d = data.frame("h"=c(1,2),"q"=c(2,3))
}

#check if data frame is NA
if(is.na(d)) {
    print("d is NA")
}
```

If `x == 1`, then it works fine without any warning, otherwise, if `x == 2` the following warning is given

```
Warning message:
In if (is.na(d)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Do you mean if `x == 2` it works fine? You can use `suppressWarnings` if you just want to supress the warnings. What do you want the function to return if `d = matrix(rep(NA, 4), nrow=2)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Irrespective of your subject line, it looks like you *really* want to check if `d` is a data frame or something else.

```
if(is.data.frame(d)) {
    # do something sensible with a data frame
}
else print("d is not a data frame!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can to set `d` to `NULL`:

```
d <- NULL
```

and then check whether `is.null(d)`

Comment: +1 - exactly what I would have recommended. `NULL` is IMHO the more appropriate *undefined* variable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my first reading was suggesting `d <- NULL` and then `is.null(d)` which is absurd (always true). It also doesn't work for `d = NA`.

Comment: Sure, but the MWE suggested that the script should return `TRUE` on `d = NA`. It seems OP has found his answer anyway :-)